# Make bash report when a subcommand takes too long?

Tags: bash

Can I configure bash to report how long each command takes to execute, if it's longer than some threshold?

I thought I recalled some setting for this, but can't find it either in bash(1) or google.

The idea, in case it's not clear, would be something like this:

```
% SUBCMDTMOUT=30
% sleep 29    # 29 seconds elapse
% sleep 30    # 30 seconds elapse
% sleep 31    # 31 seconds elapse
bash: subcommand `sleep 31' took 31 seconds to complete.
%
```

Comment: You might be thinking of the `REPORTTIME` option in `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

Prepend `time` to your command and then parse the output of `time` through any condition to get your desired output.

Example:

```
$ time sleep 15

real    0m15.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Comment: No help in this case: I'm hunting mysterious occasional delays; remembering to time everything I run is too much burden.

Answer (score 0):

@chepner probably has it right: REPORTTIME in zsh (though that only tracks CPU time; I suspect my mystery problem is some kind of network wait). But since I'm not motivated enough to convert my login shell for this, the specific answer to my question is "nope."